# How may I left-align (horizontally) the word 'Similarly' with the word 'This' in the following?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  (a+b)(a+b)=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}.
\end{equation*}
This may of course be written
\begin{flalign*}
  &&(a+b)^{2}&=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}&\\
  \makebox[0pt]{Similarly}&&
  (a-b)^{2}&= a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}&\\
  \text{In the case}&&
  (a+b)(a-b)&= a^{2}-b^{2}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `\phantom` version of the longer text (`\text{In the case}`) in order to properly align `Similarly`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  (a+b)(a+b)=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}.
\end{equation*}
This may of course be written
\begin{flalign*}
  &&(a+b)^{2}&=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2} & \\
  \rlap{Similarly}\phantom{\text{In the case}}&&
  (a-b)^{2}&= a^{2}-2ab+b^{2} & \\
  \text{In the case}&&
  (a+b)(a-b)&= a^{2}-b^{2} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit and the answer, Werner! :)

Answer (score 6):

You are already using one `\makebox` so use another one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  (a+b)(a+b)=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}.
\end{equation*}
This may of course be written
\begin{flalign*}
  &&(a+b)^{2}&=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}&\\
  \makebox[0pt][l]{Similarly}&&
  (a-b)^{2}&= a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}&\\
  \makebox[0pt][l]{In the case}&&
  (a+b)(a-b)&= a^{2}-b^{2}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your setting allows the equation that is above the text 'This may of course be written' align with the latter equations. This could certainly be of great use. Thank you very much!

Comment: the only problem with this is the vertical space after "written".  i think this is a flaw in `flalign`, but am not in a position to check right now.  (i will do so when i can.)